# Caching JSON data using Nodejs, Express

Tags: node.js, json, express, caching

I have set up an API running on my server using Nodejs and express. I am a real novice on this. I am finding with my current code that the data does not seen to be cached and needs to be downloaded to my App each time the page requests it which is slow.
I know that *Redis* does caching but I am unsure how to use it with my code. My service provider does have a Redis server instance available.
I don't want to disable my App with the wrong code, since people are currently using it.

Here is the code I am using for the API (the JSON data is truncated to make it easier to read the code). Any help would be appreciated.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
//const router = express.Router();
const port = 26695;
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// set the server to listen on port 
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));


// all of the code from the previous section should be here

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, x-http-method-override, accept, content-type, authorization, x-pingother, if-match, if-modified-since, if-none-match, if-unmodified-since, x-requested-with');
 res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'tag, link, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes');
next();
};

module.exports = function allowCORS() {

  return allowCrossDomain;

};
const cri = [{"criSingleOnly":"true","species":"All","fluids":"cri","criName":"","drugname":"Alfaxalone","dosetochange":"","perml":"mg/ml","dosemax":"0.4","dosage":"0.05","class":"loading","calcID":"Alfaxalone2L","concentration":"10","cridose":[{"dosemax":"9","dosevalue":"4","name":"Alfaxalone CRI","dosemin":"4","dosestep":"1","range":"4-9 mg/kg/hr"}],"indication":"","multiply":"1","dosevalue":"","dosestep":"0.01","route":"IV,SQ,IM","calc":"AlfaxaloneL","hide":"","appendose":" mg","loaddose":[{"dosemax":"9.7","dosevalue":"2","name":"Alfaxalone Loading","dosemin":"1.5","dosestep":"0.5","range":"1.5-9.7 mg/kg IV to Effect over 1min,IM"}],"doseT":"true","notes":"","appendvol":"","range":"","dosemin":"0.01","doseper":"0.05","perkg":"mg/kg","decimal":"2"}]


app.get("/cri", (request, response) => {
  response.send(cri);  
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand since it seems you only "download" the `cri` array once

Comment: The data is downloaded every time a user accesses a certain page which can be multiple times in a session. Being cached should speed up the subsequent times the page is accessed. (the data is a number of mb)

Comment: you could make an object full of client IPs as the keys and static versions of what they have as the `cri` value, and only send the differences

Comment: I would not have any option to get App user IP addresses due to App store  and Play store privacy restrictions.

Comment: ah, well instead of user id you can make an ID system(as in first connection gives client some token that is a unique key in your cache object server side), and have those keys with the static version of the last time u sent them the object(what the client would have) and u send the difference each time(how u do that is up to u)

Answer (score 0):

By default express doesn't provide caching out of the box. To handle caching we need to use some third party caching package. One common caching library used is Redis Cache. For details of using Redis with Express do consider checking [this Medium link](https://adostes.medium.com/adding-a-redis-cache-to-an-express-app-455c834becd1)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was aware of Redis but I would need help incorporating it or some other option into my specific (running) code without disabling my API is my issue.